# Displying Salutation field using lightning:recordEditForm on Person Account

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-recordeditform, lightning-inputfield

There is a known uncommon behavior with `Salutation` field on `Contact` object while displaying it using `lightning:recordEditForm`. Since it is a part of the compound `Name` field on `Contact`. The workaround is shown [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/215329/lightning-inputfield-component-with-salutation-field).

Also it is reported as [a known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000ATQOQA4&title=using-the-salutation-field-independently-in-lightning-recordeditform-throws-error), an old known issue since Summer '17, but still is not fixed.

This workaround applied for Contact is not working for Person Account.

```
 <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm" objectApiName="Account">
     <lightning:inputField aura:id="input-field" fieldName="Name" />
     <lightning:inputField aura:id="input-field" fieldName="FirstName" />
     <lightning:inputField aura:id="input-field" fieldName="LastName"/> 
     <lightning:inputField aura:id="input-field" fieldName="Salutation" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Results in

[image]

How to display `Salutation` field on Person Account using `lightning:recordEditForm` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your default record type id might be business account because of which Salutation will not be rendered. You should give record type id of person account in form to render `Salutation`.

You can get person account record type id using SOQL:

```
SELECT Id, Name, DeveloperName, SobjectType, IsPersonType FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType='Account' AND IsPersonType=true
```

Then give that record type id in form as below:

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm" 
                          objectApiName="Account" 
                          recordTypeId="012XXXXXXXXXXXXX">
    <div style="display:none">
        <lightning:inputField aura:id="input-field" fieldName="Name" />
    </div>
    <lightning:inputField aura:id="input-field" fieldName="FirstName" />
    <lightning:inputField aura:id="input-field" fieldName="LastName"/> 
    <lightning:inputField aura:id="input-field" fieldName="Salutation" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Comment: that works, thank you